# How can you tell if a Nikkor lens is an FX lens?

Tags: lens, nikon

How can you tell if a Nikkor lens is an FX lens?  I assume if DX is not in the nomenclature that it must be an FX lens.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to avoid lenses marked with DX (crop cameras only).

Nikkor has made optics for various optical systems, so you should also make sure the lens is an F-mount lens. Recently there were introduced 1 series lenses, meant for Nikon 1 mirrorless camera systems; these cannot be mounted to a dSLR.

Historically, lenses for Nikon rangefinders (S-mount), Nikonos underwater cameras and Contax cameras have been produced under the Nikkor brand. Technically, those *are* full-frame lenses, but need an adapter to mount to a dSLR and even then will only be usable for close-range photography due to smaller flange focal length, unless the adapter has optical elements to compensate that.